# EF 6 and sqlite code first database creation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

Can EF 6 create a sqlite database with the code first approach? i have tried to google but cant find any good answers.

Comment: EF6 changed its provider model. I don't believe SQLite packages have been updated to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [Sqllitenet](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net)

It is the closest thing non-EntityFramework that will work well cross-platform.

You'll be out of luck on Updates.  You'll have to use manual SQL for any object updates, but for inserts / deletes you'll be just peachy.